# what is webservice url for getting all online stores for a particular product using google proguct search api?

Tags: iphone, google-product-search, google-shopping-api

Hi 
I had the product name....
I need to get all the online stores available for that product.
But i have to use google product search API
Can you please give the URL for searching online stores for that product......

Thanks in advance..

Comment: So what exactly are you asking for? You seem to know the link to http://www.google.com/products

Comment: No. had product name..and need to get the online stores(they should sell that product).. if i click the product link, i should navigate to that online store(ebay, amazon, bestbuy) page...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google [Search API for shopping](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/), you can diversify results to one per vendor, with a query for the product name such as::

```
https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?q=apple+iphone+4&country=US&alt=json&key=KEY&crowdBy=accountId%3A1
```

Note, you will need to get your own [developer key](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and put it in the KEY parameter.